# How to restrict button unless text boxes have text

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I am wanting to prevent my submit buttons from being selected untill the user has entered text into my text box feilds.. I have looked into Jquery but am not sure how to apply it to my situations.

if you look at the code below I have a table, this is a section where I can add values to a table in my BD I have 3 other different tables similar but not the same each with their own submit buttons i want to restrict also but off their own text boxes not the others from the different tables...

how could I achive this?

heres one of the tables I have created.

```
<table width="600">
    <tr>
        <td width="15%">
            <b>name:</b> 
            <div class="qlabs_tooltip_bottom qlabs_tooltip_style_7">
                <input type="text" name="5050gdproductname" />
            <span>Enter Text </br>i.e. <i>Super Small</i></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="15%">
            <b>width:</b> 
            <div class="qlabs_tooltip_bottom qlabs_tooltip_style_7">
                <input type="text" name="5050gdproductwidth" />
            <span>Enter a Number </br>i.e. <i>1000</i></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="15%">
            <b>height:</b> 
            <div class="qlabs_tooltip_bottom qlabs_tooltip_style_7">
                <input type="text" name="5050gdproductheight" />
            <span>Enter a Number </br>i.e. <i>1000</i></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="15%">
            <b>normal fill:</b> 
            <div class="qlabs_tooltip_bottom qlabs_tooltip_style_7">
                <input type="text" name="5050gdnormalfill" />
            <span>Enter a Number </br>i.e. <i>1000</i></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="15%">
            <b>our fill:</b> 
            <div class="qlabs_tooltip_bottom qlabs_tooltip_style_7">
                <input type="text" name="5050gdourfill" />
                <span>Enter a Number </br>i.e. <i>1000</i></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="15%">
            <b>old price:</b> 
            <div class="qlabs_tooltip_bottom qlabs_tooltip_style_7">
                <input type="text" name="5050gdoldprice" />
            <span>Enter Dollar Amount </br>i.e. <i>150.99</i></br>no dollar sign requiered</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="15%">
            <b>new price:</b> 
            <div class="qlabs_tooltip_bottom qlabs_tooltip_style_7">
                <input type="text" name="5050gdnewprice" /> 
            <span>Enter Dollar Amount </br>i.e. <i>150.99</i></br>no dollar sign requiered</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            </br><input type="submit" name="submit5050gd" value="Submit 5050gd" id="5050gdmyButton" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You mean you want disable the submit button until form fields gets filled out?

Comment: explanation is not giving an idea of what you want. try to simplify the situation.

Comment: @LearneR yes sorry thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: @HurkNburkS
I have not tested my code but you can use the approach as it is fast and effecient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle link for your assistance:

http://jsfiddle.net/4JyLk/

1. handle in Button click event
2. If all text boxes are given values, proceed with submission else don't.

Use the link provided for live demo.

Note: You can edit this code, to disable/enable.

Comment: So I just tried using your code staight out of the gate to see if the submit worked.. however it didnt.. so it makes me think I am doing something wrong.. I am refrencing my javascript file like so **<script src="validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**

Comment: and the file is sitting in the same directory and is exactly what you have on your link.

Comment: ahha.. got it.. thanks very much i was doing the wrong thing with the js.. your example helped me heaps.. however this has definatly slowed my code up.. thanks tho.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=text]')​.keyup(function(){
    if(($('input[name=5050gdproductname]').val()=="")||($('input[name=5050gdproductwidth]').val()=="")||($('input[name=5050gdproductheight]').val()=="")||($('input[name=5050gdnormalfill]').val()=="")||($('input[name=5050gdourfill]').val()=="")||($('input[name=5050gdoldprice]').val()=="")||($('input[name=5050gdnewprice]').val()==""))
    {
     $('input[name=submit5050gd]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');     
}else{
    $('input[name=submit5050gd]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    });​​​​

<input type="submit" name="submit5050gd" value="Submit 5050gd" id="5050gdmyButton" disabled="disabled"/>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/bjtQY/1/)

Comment: I have tried this code but it is not working for me.. It disables the button but then once I have entered stuff into it it still dosnt become enabled.

Comment: I am using your exact code and it just dosnt work for me. I have even added **<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"/>**

Comment: yea I saw that.. I will try replacing my code with yours as I have just re-writen it.. do I put the **$('input[type=tex....** inside the  **<script type="text/javascript">** I have never used / seen this jsFiddle so not sure what might be missing or not

Comment: can you show your jquery code? and sure your jquery script tag is correct

Comment: I just copy / pasted your code word for word.. and i cannot get it to work :P

Comment: put my code inside the '$(document).read(function(){ ..mycode.. });'

Comment: I cant figure it out so gonna do some more reading before I come back an mark this. blinking painfull just not sure where to actually put the code.

Comment: I found out I had to put the function into a .js file which I have done and am refrenceing now but its still not working on my page.

Comment: I think you should download jquery and use it in local machine I provide a sample maybe help http://www.mediafire.com/?33wkc1zo5yt4jt3

Comment: i think this code doesnt work if i directly click on submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit5050gd" value="Submit 5050gd" id="5050gdmyButton" disabled='disabled" />
```

On the last text box use the [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event of javascript to validate your condition.

Try this.

```
var isBlank = false;
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function(){        
$("#YourTableID").find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ''){
      isBlank = true;
      return false;
    }
});
if(!isBlank){
        $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}

});
```

Comment: The condition will never be true, the value of an input is a string whose minimum length is 0, so it can never be `< 0`. Anyway, far simpler and more obvious to test `if (this.value == '')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
//On document load
    $(function(){
          //Set button disabled
          $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

          //Append a change event listener to you inputs
          $('input').change(function(){
                //Validate your form here, example:
                var validated = true;
                if($('#5050gdnormalfill').val().length === 0) validated = false;
                //do validation for all field as above, add id field for every element

                //If form is validated enable form
                if(validated) $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");                              
          });


    })
```

Comment: this code is a flaw if the text boxes are shown pre populated in the html page....

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers, all confusing to me. Far better to validate the form when it's sumbitted and don't do things like disable the submit button. If you want all the text inputs to have text, then:

```
function validate(form) {
    var el, elements = form.elements;

    for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        el = elements[i];

        if (el.tagName.toLowerCase == 'input' &&  el.type == 'text') {
            if (el.value == '') {

                // Deal with error, e.g. show message

                // Stop form submitting
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the form:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validate(this);" ...>
```

You can also put a listener for change or keyup events on every text input, then run the above code and disable the submit button, so instead of `return false` you'd do:

```
  form.submit5050gd.disabled = true;
```

to disable the button or:

```
  form.submit5050gd.disabled = false;
```

to enable it. But that's a bit tiresom and users tend to not understand disabled controls. Much better to just let them know they have to put something in each input and validate when they submit the form.